# django admin popups properties arent shown

Tags: html, django, django-templates, django-admin, django-cms

When I want to change plugin in admin site or edit existing one (no matter which one I open). Properties in popup aren't shown or if they are, they aren't on right positions.

When pop up shows to edit plugin I can't click save. I must scroll out page (ctr and -) to see save button. It's not only save button, most of properties aren't shown properly.

if I add any more placeholders, I am not able to see save button, even with zooming out. The problems only appears in django admin site, where I want to add plugins.

Without bootstrap template I can't place a lot of placeholders without affect djangoadmin popups.

How can I fix this?

**base.html :**

```
{% load cms_tags sekizai_tags %}
<html>
  <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<title>{% page_attribute "page_title" %}</title>
      {% render_block "css" %}

  </head>
  <body>

      {% cms_toolbar %}

      {% block base_content %}{% endblock %}
      {% render_block "js" %}



  <footer>
  {% static_placeholder 'footer' %}
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

**template_two.html :**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load cms_tags %}
<html>
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
    {% block base_content %}
    <body id="myPage" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="60">
    
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#myPage">Logo</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#services">SERVICES</a></li>
            <li><a href="#portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
            <li><a href="#pricing">PRICING</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}<li><a href="{% url 'PostShow' %}">Messages</a></li>
            {% else %}aa{% endif %}
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> {% if user.is_authenticated %}<li><a href="/logout">Log Out</a>
    <li><a href="{% url 'home' %}">{{request.user.username}}</a></li>
              </li>
          {% else %}
          <li><a href="/login">Log In</a></li>
          {% endif %}</a></li>
          </ul>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    
     {% placeholder  aa %}
    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
      <h1>Company</h1>
      <p>We specialize in blablabla</p>
      <form class="form-inline">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" size="50" placeholder="Email Address" required>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Subscribe</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <!-- Container (About Section) -->
    <div id="about" class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <h2>About Company Page</h2><br>
          <br><button class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Get in Touch</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-signal logo"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="container-fluid bg-grey">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe logo slideanim"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <h2>Our Values</h2><br>
          <h4><strong>MISSION:</strong> {% placeholder mission %}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Container (Services Section) -->
    <div id="services" class="container-fluid text-center">
      <h2>SERVICES</h2>
      <h4>What we offer</h4>
      <br>
      <div class="row slideanim">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off logo-small"></span>
          <h4>POWER</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart logo-small"></span>
          <h4>LOVE</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock logo-small"></span>
          <h4>JOB DONE</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br><br>
      <div class="row slideanim">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-leaf logo-small"></span>
          <h4>GREEN</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-certificate logo-small"></span>
          <h4>CERTIFIED</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench logo-small"></span>
          <h4 style="color:#303030;">HARD WORK</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Container (Portfolio Section) -->
    <div id="portfolio" class="container-fluid text-center bg-grey">
      <h2>Portfolio</h2><br>
      <h4>What we have created</h4>
      <div class="row text-center slideanim">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="paris.jpg" alt="Paris" width="400" height="300">
            <p><strong>Paris</strong></p>
            <p>Yes, we built Paris</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="newyork.jpg" alt="New York" width="400" height="300">
            <p><strong>New York</strong></p>
            <p>We built New York</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="sanfran.jpg" alt="San Francisco" width="400" height="300">
            <p><strong>San Francisco</strong></p>
            <p>Yes, San Fran is ours</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><br>
    
      <h2>What our customers say</h2>
      <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide text-center" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
    
        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="item active">
            <h4>"This company is the best. I am so happy with the result!"<br><span style="font-style:normal;">Michael Roe, Vice President, Comment Box</span></h4>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <h4>"One word... WOW!!"<br><span style="font-style:normal;">John Doe, Salesman, Rep Inc</span></h4>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <h4>"Could I... BE any more happy with this company?"<br><span style="font-style:normal;">Chandler Bing, Actor, FriendsAlot</span></h4>
          </div>
        </div>
    
        <!-- Left and right controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Container (Pricing Section) -->
    <div id="pricing" class="container-fluid">
      <div class="text-center">
        <h2>Pricing</h2>
        <h4>Choose a payment plan that works for you</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="row slideanim">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
          <div class="panel panel-default text-center">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h1>Basic</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <p><strong>20</strong> Lorem</p>
              <p><strong>15</strong> Ipsum</p>
              <p><strong>5</strong> Dolor</p>
              <p><strong>2</strong> Sit</p>
              <p><strong>Endless</strong> Amet</p>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">
              <h3>$19</h3>
              <h4>per month</h4>
              <button class="btn btn-lg">Sign Up</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
          <div class="panel panel-default text-center">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h1>Pro</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <p><strong>50</strong> Lorem</p>
              <p><strong>25</strong> Ipsum</p>
              <p><strong>10</strong> Dolor</p>
              <p><strong>5</strong> Sit</p>
              <p><strong>Endless</strong> Amet</p>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">
              <h3>$29</h3>
              <h4>per month</h4>
              <button class="btn btn-lg">Sign Up</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
          <div class="panel panel-default text-center">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h1>Premium</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <p><strong>100</strong> Lorem</p>
              <p><strong>50</strong> Ipsum</p>
              <p><strong>25</strong> Dolor</p>
              <p><strong>10</strong> Sit</p>
              <p><strong>Endless</strong> Amet</p>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">
              <h3>$49</h3>
              <h4>per month</h4>
              <button class="btn btn-lg">Sign Up</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Container (Contact Section) -->
    <div id="contact" class="container-fluid bg-grey">
      <h2 class="text-center">CONTACT</h2>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-5">
          <p>Contact us and we'll get back to you within 24 hours.</p>
          <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span> Chicago, US</p>
          <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></span> +00 1515151515</p>
          <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> myemail@something.com</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-7 slideanim">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
              <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
              <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="email" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <textarea class="form-control" id="comments" name="comments" placeholder="Comment" rows="5"></textarea><br>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
              <button class="btn btn-default pull-right" type="submit">Send</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="googleMap" style="height:400px;width:100%;"></div>
    
    <!-- Add Google Maps -->
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script>
    var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(41.878114, -87.629798);
    
    function initialize() {
    var mapProp = {
      center:myCenter,
      zoom:12,
      scrollwheel:false,
      draggable:false,
      mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
    
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
    
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position:myCenter,
      });
    
    marker.setMap(map);
    }
    
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
    
    <footer class="container-fluid text-center">
      <a href="#myPage" title="To Top">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
      </a>
      <p>Bootstrap Theme Made By <a href="http://www.w3schools.com" title="Visit w3schools">www.w3schools.com</a></p>
    </footer>
    
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      // Add smooth scrolling to all links in navbar + footer link
      $(".navbar a, footer a[href='#myPage']").on('click', function(event) {
        // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
        if (this.hash !== "") {
          // Prevent default anchor click behavior
          event.preventDefault();
    
          // Store hash
          var hash = this.hash;
    
          // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
          // The optional number (900) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
          $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
          }, 900, function(){
    
            // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
            window.location.hash = hash;
          });
        } // End if
      });
    
      $(window).scroll(function() {
        $(".slideanim").each(function(){
          var pos = $(this).offset().top;
    
          var winTop = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (pos < winTop + 600) {
              $(this).addClass("slide");
            }
        });
      });
    })
    </script>
    
    
      </body>
    {% endblock

 %}
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the developer console to see if any files are missing during the plugin load. There you should be able to see if any static files are missing.

Also, please make sure that your static files are configured properly - i.e. that you have ran `manage.py collectstatic` and the static URL points to the right location.

Comment: Hey,
In log console there is no 404 error. Im having problems with width and height of popup. More html code and more placeholders affect on increasing this two propertys.
thanks for help

Comment: Is there a chance for you to deploy the code for other people to have a look how it's working?